# WCF Service methods called twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

**I have a wcf service with the following web.config in the server.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
    <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconnection" connectionString="myconnectionstr"/>
   </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
          <services>
             <service behaviorConfiguration="PSWebServis.PServisBehavior" name="PSWebServis.PServis">
                     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PSWebServis.IPServis" />  
                 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
                 <host>
                      <baseAddresses>
                           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/" />  
                </baseAddresses>  
            </host>  
        </service> 
    </services>  
       <behaviors>
           <serviceBehaviors>       
               <behavior name="PSWebServis.PServisBehavior">
                       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" /> 
                   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" /> 
            </behavior>  
        </serviceBehaviors> 
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**and this is related part in web.config in client.**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPServis" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://sunucu:8000/PServis.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPServis" contract="PSWebServis.IPServis"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IPServis">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/SUNUCU" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

**Here is a part of my interface in the service**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPServis
{
    [OperationContract]
    string InsertMusteri(MusterilerModel musteri);
}
```

**and related part in service class.**

```
public class PServis : IPServis
{
    public string InsertMusteri(MusterilerModel musteri)
    {
        if (musteri != null)
        {

            DataTable dtSonuc = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertMusteriModel", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@musteriTablo", musteri.KayitTablosu);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefonTablo", musteri.TelefonKayit);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresTablo", musteri.AdresKayit);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            adapter.Fill(dtSonuc);
            connection.Close();

            return dtSonuc.Rows[0]["IslemDurum"].ToString();
        }

        return "Başarısız";
    }
 }
```

**My MusterilerModel class:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MusterilerModel
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public int MusteriID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Ad { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Soyad { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=3)]
    public string KullaniciAdi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string Email { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime DogumTarihi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=6)]
    public string GrupAdi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=7)]
    public int Renk { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=8)]
    public decimal Bakiye { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=9)]
    public string Adres { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=10)]
    public string AdresAciklamasi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=11)]
    public string Firma { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=12)]
    public string VergiDairesi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=13)]
    public string VergiNo { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=14)]
    public int BayiID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=15)]
    public string Il { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 16)]
    public string Ilce { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order = 17)]
    public decimal YemekPara { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=18)]
    public string Sifre { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=19)]
    public int GrupID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=20)]
    public string BayiAdi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=21)]
    public int SehirID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=22)]
    public int IlceID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=23)]
    public DateTime EvlilikYilDonumu { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=24)]
    public DateTime KayitTarihi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=25)]
    public string KayitEdenPersonel { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=26)]
    public int KayitEdenPersonelID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=27)]
    public bool AktifMi { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=28)]
    public string Aciklama { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=29)]
    public string OzelKod { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=30)]
    public int SatisID { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Order=31)]
    public DataTable KayitTablosu { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Order=32)]
    public DataTable TelefonKayit { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Order=33)]
    public DataTable AdresKayit { set; get; }
 }
```

When i try to use InsertMusteri method, there are 2 records in the database. As you see, i put my information into datatable and send it to the service. I checked, if datatable has more than 1 value but that was not the problem. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment this line

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And check if it's work properly.
I think "Fill" command executs your command.

Comment: thank you very much ! I didnt notice that part. That took me days to solve. I am very grateful. u saved my life :D thanks again.